# Different logging configurations per enviroment, good or bad?

Tags: java, logging

I'm currently using a very basic logging configuration and I'm using the same configuration in all environments. For development it is beneficial to see the output in the console, so I've configured log4j with the following root categories:

`log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console, file`

When I deploy, I am only interested in the output that is directed to file and have configured each file to have maximum file size.

Is there any performance hit of logging to console in production where I have no use for it? Also, where does this output go in a Linux vs. a Windows machine when no console is available? What, if anything, do I gain by having separate configurations?

Comment: Note that more modern systems (switching from log4j to slf4j is a good idea) tend to have *built-in* support for changing log configurations based on profiles/environments.

Comment: It's a legacy system, I can change the log4j properties by simply editing an external file and I don't have to recompile.